# Get the original parsed number from FloatingLiteral/APFloat

Tags: c++, clang, llvm, llvm-clang, llvm-ir

I started to use clang as a frontend to a bounded model checker I'm currently working on and I need some help with float number that I get from the AST.

For example, for this program:

```
int main()
{
  float a = 1.0f;
  long double b = 5567.765434376l;
}
```

The generated AST is:

```
FunctionDecl 0x1dea160 </home/mramalho/main.c:3:1, line:7:1> line:3:5 main 'int ()'
`-CompoundStmt 0x1dea368 <line:4:1, line:7:1>
  |-DeclStmt 0x1dea298 <line:5:3, col:17>
  | `-VarDecl 0x1dea218 <col:3, col:13> col:9 a 'float' cinit
  |   `-FloatingLiteral 0x1dea278 <col:13> 'float' 1.000000e+00
  `-DeclStmt 0x1dea350 <line:6:3, col:34>
    `-VarDecl 0x1dea2c0 <col:3, col:19> col:15 b 'long double' cinit
      `-FloatingLiteral 0x1dea320 <col:19> 'long double' 5.567765e+03
```

The APFLoat number I get from .getValue() doesn't help much since it's stored as the already converted number.

In particular, I would like to know if it's possible to get the original number (in the example above, 1.0f and 5567.765434376l). If possible, having the string for (+/-)Inf and/or NaN when applicable would be great but not required.

I tried several way but I always end up with a trimmed version of the original number.

My best bet is on a method convertFromString and the struct DecimalInfo (both on APFloat), but I can't find a way to reach them since the number is already created by the time I get the FloatingLiteral.

Thank you.

Answer (score 4):

Don't know if it's OK to answer your own questions but here is how I solved it:

```
llvm::SmallVector<char, 32> string;
val.toString(string, 32, 0);
```

Where val is an APFloat. From the documentation:

```
/// Converts this value into a decimal string.
///
/// \param FormatPrecision The maximum number of digits of
///   precision to output.  If there are fewer digits available,
///   zero padding will not be used unless the value is
///   integral and small enough to be expressed in
///   FormatPrecision digits.  0 means to use the natural
///   precision of the number.
/// \param FormatMaxPadding The maximum number of zeros to
///   consider inserting before falling back to scientific
///   notation.  0 means to always use scientific notation.
///
/// Number       Precision    MaxPadding      Result
/// ------       ---------    ----------      ------
/// 1.01E+4              5             2       10100
/// 1.01E+4              4             2       1.01E+4
/// 1.01E+4              5             1       1.01E+4
/// 1.01E-2              5             2       0.0101
/// 1.01E-2              4             2       0.0101
/// 1.01E-2              4             1       1.01E-2
```

Then it's a simple iteration to get the value.

It also gives "Inf" string for infinity values.

Comment: Not only is it OK but encouraged. Glad you got there in the end.